# Java Nashorn build json array object in java can't find way

Tags: java, json, nashorn

I try to create java json array , 
can't find any way to create them using Nashorn 
i can create simple objects ...

```
private void createJsonObject() {
        try {

            final Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>();
            newMap.put("foo",1);
            newMap.put("bar", true);

            ScriptObjectMirror json = (ScriptObjectMirror) this.engine.eval("JSON");
            json.putAll(newMap);

            this.engine.put("jsonObject", json);
            String result = (String) this.engine.eval("JSON.stringify(jsonObject)");
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Result :      {"bar":true,"foo":1}

Here i try to create array but im getting empty json

```
 private void createJsonObject() {
        try {


            List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
            returnList.add("x");
            returnList.add("y");
            ScriptObjectMirror json = (ScriptObjectMirror) this.engine.eval("JSON");         
            json.put("test",returnList);
            this.engine.put("jsonObject", json);
            String result = (String) this.engine.eval("JSON.stringify(jsonObject)");
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Result:     {}

The end goal is to build array of objects in memory using java native tools without using dependencies